# jquery validation label positioning not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, message

There are quite some posts about this in stackoverflow.
Most of them are saying using the errorClass, errorElement, errorLabelContainer, errorContainer, errorPlacement which is stated in the documentation but somehow I couldn't get them to work.

I found the best one for me should be using the `errorPlacement` so I can `appened` it easily for positioning but still have no luck getting it to work.

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
        <form method="post" class="user-info-form" id="user-pickup-info-form" action="{% url 'checkout:shipping-method' %}">
            <input type="hidden" name="method_code" value="{{ method.code }}" />
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                <label for="id_title" class="control-label">
                    Name
                </label><input class="form-control pickup_name" type="text" name="pickup_name" required="required" />
                <label for="id_title" class="control-label">
                Phone number
                </label><input class="form-control pickup_phone" type="text" name="pickup_phone" required="required" />
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary margin-t2 margin-b2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-loading-text="{% trans 'Submitting...' %}">Submitbutton>
        </form>
```

jQuery

```
        $('#user-pickup-info-form').validate({
            rules: {
               pickup_name: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 2
               },
                pickup_phone: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 10
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.prev() );
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is giving wrong? I tried this code and it worked. https://fiddle.jshell.net/aneukirchen/kjscg5s5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three errors:

- the ***rules: {*** section must be closed before the errorPlacement section
- the labels have the save for attribute "id_title".
- the submit button is not closed: Submitbutton> This must be: Submit</button>

The snippet:

```js
$('#user-pickup-info-form').validate({
  rules: {
    pickup_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    pickup_phone: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 10
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo( element.prev() );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" class="user-info-form" id="user-pickup-info-form" action="{% url 'checkout:shipping-method' %}">
    <input type="hidden" name="method_code" value="{{ method.code }}"/>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <label for="id_title1" class="control-label">
            Name
        </label><input id="id_title1" class="form-control pickup_name" type="text" name="pickup_name"
                       required="required"/>
        <label for="id_title2" class="control-label">
            Phone number
        </label><input id="id_title2" class="form-control pickup_phone" type="text" name="pickup_phone"
                       required="required"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary margin-t2 margin-b2" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"
            data-loading-text="{% trans 'Submitting...' %}">Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: omg, been kept on trying it and it's because I put the `errorPlacement` inside `rules` thx a lot~